# HERE API Autocomplete Country Code ISO Alpha 2

Tags: here-api

Is there a way to receive the ISO Alpha-2 country code from the HERE autocomplete API instead of the 3-letter ISO country codes? The documentation (https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder-autocomplete/dev_guide/topics/resource-suggest.html) doesn't say anything about this but other APIs from HERE do return the Alpha-2 code.
If the API itself doesn't do it, is there another API we can use to convert the country code? 
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, the API would return always a 3 Letter ISO country code. There is no API available from HERE APIs to convert the codes either. It should be possible to create a mapping based on ISO service directly (https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#search)